# Need help for: "auto-py-to-exe"

Tags: python

at first... sorry for my bad english.
i try my best to explain my problem.

i try to make an .exe from an simple python file... that worked fine.
but when i execute these file it just runs the first lines of code an never touches the rest.

```
import random
import time
import os

clear = lambda: os.system("cls")

o = ["loading system files","etablishing connection","root network","checking network connectivity","open backdoor","inject rootkit"]

ini = 0

while ini <= 5:
    oo = random.randint(1,len(o))
    print(o[oo-1])
    time.sleep(1.5)
    clear()
    ini += 1
    
    
loading = 0
dot = "."
print("sys/boot: ", end="")
while loading <= 20:
    num_alpha = random.randint(1,3)
    time.sleep(1)
    print(dot, end="")
    dot += (dot*num_alpha)
    loading += 1
    if len(dot) >= 20:
        break
clear()

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"steel","supply","secure","density","stream","penalty","huge","set","struggle","complication","sculpture","consultation","shock""remove","agreement","strong","brake","amount","number","futuristic","quilt","lick","nose","quack","dare","kittens","trap","actually","unbecoming","meal","skinny","judge",
"twin","gem","tidy","jungle","policy","gap","attraction","texture"," ","_","#","/","??","!"," ","network","199.0.2.100","html","hate","1293==?!","&/(&/","§","########","##","+++++","...","***","`?","MMK",";:_","!))!","Stabilisierung des Netzwerkes gesscheitert...","ERRNR: PX990-OOPJK-LAz//Da","pro:_extiction","lab: alpha//dtz//omega..._closed//","connection_closed","alpha_strike//ERROR","NUMBER_10_release"]

while True:
    
    for i in x:
        time.sleep(0.09)
        num = random.randint(1,len(x))
        print(x[num-1], end=" ")
```

I absolutly dont know what to do next, has anyone an idea?

Comment: Which first lines? How do you know it never reaches the rest?

Comment: the first lines of the code are executed in the prompt that opens after i execut the file.
but then nothing more happens.
the rest of the code stays untouched.

Comment: The first line is `import random`. How do you know only this line is executed? You have `time.sleep`s, maybe you just need to wait?

Comment: oh! sorry, i was not that clear i need to... ^^"

`o = ["loading system files","etablishing connection","root network","checking network connectivity","open backdoor","inject rootkit"]

ini = 0

while ini <= 5:
    oo = random.randint(1,len(o))
    print(o[oo-1])
    time.sleep(1.5)
    clear()
    ini += 1
`
thats to part of the code that is executed